# How to set zdir in Axes3D of matplotlib to get better waterfall

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am planning to plot waterfall like figures from multi-text data files, `x` is the wavelength, `y` are the responses, `z` is the frame number. `x` and `y` have the same dimensions(e.x. 5000 data). Basically, simplified my code is something like the following, I find I can not get the right view. What I want is the z-axis and y-axis be exchanged,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

x =  arange(0.0, 10, 0.04)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for z in range(0,8):
    y = sin(2*x*pi*z) 
    ax.plot(x, y, z )

plt.xlabel(' x', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
plt.ylabel(' y', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[with the "zdir='y'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apizz.png)

[Without zdir='y'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL4Nw.png)

What I want is Z-axis and y-axis be exchanged in Fig2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle using `zdir="y"` seems the correct approach. That would however mean to supply the `y` argument as last one in the call,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

x =  arange(0.0, 10, 0.04)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for y in list(range(0,8))[::-1]:
    z = sin(2*x*pi*y) 
    ax.plot(x, z ,y, zdir="y")

plt.xlabel(' x', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
plt.ylabel(' y', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
ax.set_ylim(0,9)
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, you can achieve this with `np.arange`, but you can define `x` and `y` with [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin, pi, linspace

x =  linspace(0.0, 10, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for k in range(1, 4):
    #sine wave with amplitude modulation by k
    z = sin(2 * x * pi) * k + k
    #keeping y constant for each k
    y = linspace(k, k, 100)

    ax.plot(x, y, z )

plt.xlabel(' x', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
plt.ylabel(' y', fontsize = 12, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

Difference here is that `np.linspace` has as parameter number of steps, while `np.arange` uses the step size.